# How can I change spells (using hotkeys) in a spell+shield configuration?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I like how the PC version of Skyrim lets you use the number keys to switch quickly between spells, but its awkward to use this capability when you are in a spell + shield configuration. As far as I can tell shields can only be equipped in the left hand, and this is unfortunately the same hand used to equip a spell when you press the assigned number key.

I want a setup where I can press the number keys to select different spells for my right hand while keeping the shield equipped on my left hand. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out one way to do this but its pretty clumsy. The key is that double tapping a spell key will equip the spell in both hands. So I have my hotkeys as follows:

```
1 - Shield
2 - Spell A
3 - Spell B
etc
```

If I want to equip shield + spell A, I hit 2, 2, 1. This will equip spell A to both hands and then put the shield back into the left hand.

If I want to swap to shield + spell B, I hit 3, 3, 1.

This works but I would still much prefer a simpler way.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a simpeler way

Comment: Very necessary tip thanks Paul. Would be a shame if there really is no easier way.