# Dual wielding daggers with numeric shortcuts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've assigned num 5 for to my Daedric Dagger and num 2 to my Blade of Woe. When I tap 2 or 5, the weapon in my sword-hand gets replaced. in order to actually dual wield, I need to open up the favorites menu, and left click/right click to make it happen.

Is there a known way, by which I can change the controls to dual wield upon tapping?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently the only way to dual wield weapons with a hotkey is if you have two of the exact same items.  Otherwise, the behavior is exactly what you experience (you replace the right hand with a new weapon).

There have been numerous mod requests of this on the modding forums for the PC, I'm sure something will come out for it eventually.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the answer. I did not know that having two weapons of the same name can get you to dual wield. I'm now sporting two daedric daggers :)

Comment: Actually, no. This is not working as expected. There appear to be multiple bugs. If I tap 2 twice, the dagger just appears in one hand and then disappears. Then the '2' shortcut mysteriously gets disabled.

Comment: The game does not appear to be able to handle 2 items of the exact configuration in the favorites menu.

Comment: @desaiw Your daggers has to be able to stack (exactly same name and same enchantment) in your inventory for this to work.  If they have different enchantments, then they won't stack and you can't do it.

Comment: @Aditya what you want to do is assign 1 hot key to your stack of 2 daggers, and just push that hot key twice.  Don't assign 2 hot keys  (1 per dagger)

Comment: @adityamenon sometimes your favorited hot key for your dagger may become unassigned, this is yet another glitch with Skyrim (don't know how to work around it), but if you have two daedric daggers, put in your favorites menu, make sure both are unequipped, assign them to hot key 1, just double tap hot key 1 at any time to dual wield both.

Comment: That does not seem to help :( I assigned both Daedric daggers to '1' - it displays as "1. Daedric Dagger (Legendary) (2)" in my favorites. But when I tap 1 once, I can draw it one hand. Tapping 1 twice de-equips it and also removes the hotkey. This really is weird, because spells are quite smooth to dual equip...

Comment: unmodified weapons work as yx. claims.  Smithing upgraded weapons work as aditya claims.

Answer (score 7):

If you want use two different daggers, I believe this *will* actually be possible, using the same method as described here for spell-shield configurations:

[How can I change spells (using hotkeys) in a spell+shield configuration?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37730/how-can-i-change-spells-using-hotkeys-in-a-spellshield-configuration)

For this you will need to have *two* of one of the daggers, and one of the other. Assign hotkey 2 to the dagger you have two of. Assign hotkey 1 to the other dagger. Then when you press 2-2-1 you put dagger 2 into the right hand and dagger 1 into the left hand.

Comment: nice trick.  You are right, this works nicely, the only downside is the main hand dagger can't be something special but a base dagger that's stackable.